# slick.js How to make it visible for carousel thumbnail videos without hiding in mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I can able to show 3 thumbnail carousel videos in desktop but I wanted to show all video thumbnails only in mobile device (I mean to show all carousel thumbnail videos), please help me out.

```js
videoCarousel: function() {
  $(".slider-for").slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    infinite: false,
    initialSlide: 0,
    arrows: false,
    fade: !0,
    asNavFor: ".slider-nav"
  });

  $(".slider-nav").slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    infinite: false,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    swipeToSlide: true,
    asNavFor: ".slider-for",
    vertical: true,
    arrows: false,
    dots: false,
    centerMode: false,
    swipeToSlide: true,
    focusOnSelect: true,
    draggable: false,
    responsive: [
      { breakpoint: 767 }
    ]
  });
}
```

Comment: Check the snippet code, is not running, you need to add some html code

Comment: I don't have a static HTML code...Which is developed in AEM from the back end it was developed. If you have any suggestion it would be great.